# Neural network with several input parameters and several output parameters

Tags: python, tensorflow, neural-network

I have started to deal with Tensorflow.
In an exercise on Udacity I learned to create a neural network that can convert Celsius to Fahrenheit.
For training the neural net was given 3 examples:

```
celsius_q = np.array([-40, -10, 0, 8, 15, 22, 38], dtype=float)
fahrenheit_a = np.array([-40, 14, 32, 46, 59, 72, 100], dtype=float)
```

Now I would like to deal with a more complex problem.
I have a measurement series with 3 measurement series as examples. For each measurement series I have 4 input parameters (Inputs) and 3 corresponding measured values (Outputs).

[image: Data]

I now want to create a neural network and give it the 3 measurement series to train. 
Then I want to enter a set of input parameters and the neural network should give me the outputs.

I took the existing code from my exercise on Udacity and tried to convert it to my use case.

Unfortunately, I have not yet achieved success. The code is here:

## Import

```
import tensorflow as tf
import numpy as np
```

## Set up training data

```
inputMatrix = np.array([(100,230,0.95,100),
                        (200,245,0.99,121),
                        ( 40,250,0.91,123)],dtype=float)
outputMatrix = np.array([(120, 5,120),
                         (123,24,100),
                         (154, 3,121)],dtype=float)
for i,c in enumerate(inputMatrix):
print("{}Input Matrix={}Output Matrix".format(c,outputMatrix[i]))
```

## Create the Model

```
l0 = tf.keras.layers.Dense(units = 4, input_shape = [4])
l1 = tf.keras.layers.Dense(units = 64)
l2 = tf.keras.layers.Dense(units = 128)
l3 = tf.keras.layers.Dense(units = 3)

model = tf.keras.Sequential([l0,l1,l2,l3])
```

## Compile the Model

```
model.compile(loss='mean_squared_error', optimizer=tf.keras.optimizers.Adam(0.1))
```

## Train the model

```
history = model.fit(inputMatrix,outputMatrix,epochs=500,verbose=False)
print("Finished training the model!")
```

## Display training statistics

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
plt.xlabel('Epoch Number')
plt.ylabel('Loss Magnitude')
plt.plot(history.history['loss'])
```

## Use the model to predict values

```
print(model.predict([120,260,0.98,110]))`
```

I think a problem is that under "Set up training data" the 3 measurement series are not implemented correctly.

If I execute the code under "Train the Model", the training is finished very quickly, which should not be the case with such a complex task.

I hope someone can help me learn step by step and solve this problem.

Comment: what should be the output values?

Comment: I get `134.3495     4.957284 141.96487 `. is this correct?

Comment: The values are not real values. It is just a example. How did you get the software to work?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The only issue I see in the code is that the shape of the input expected is of shape 1,4

```
print(model.predict(np.array([120,260,0.98,110]).reshape(1,4)))
```

Comment: Thank you. It works! Now I will check if I get plausible values with plausible examples.

Comment: One more question: Is my approach to solve the problem good? Or is my approach not so suitable for the problem and there are better methods?